# C++ std::sort with identical arguments

Tags: c++, sorting, std

I'm reading someone else's code, and I see something like this:

```
sort(myvec.begin(),  myvec.begin());
```

I wrote some code to test it, and it seems to do the same thing as

```
sort(myvec.begin(),  myvec.end());
```

Do they really do the same thing?   Is that documented?  Is there a way to understand why, or was it just an arbitrary choice to implement it in that way?

**Update after answers**

Yes, it's a no-op.  My test code had a bug.

Comment: In the first case, `std::sort` should not do anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code

```
sort(myvec.begin(),  myvec.begin());
```

should be a no-op, since that's an empty range. The code

```
sort(myvec.begin(),  myvec.end());
```

will sort the entire contents of `myvec`. If these happen to do the same thing, it means that your vector was already sorted. The first line is almost certainly a typo or a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are just a way of specifying range. You must have bad intuitions about them if you have even thought that this code could work properly. What if we used method that takes 2 indices -> begin index of the part of vector being sorted and the index indicating end of it. Would `sort(0, myvec.size())` and `sort(0, 0)` be equivalent?

This code should undoubtly be `sort(myvec.begin(),  myvec.end());`